# Not able to increase the size of EditText Box in android

Tags: android, size, android-edittext

I am trying to make the layout of signup form. But the size of EditText box is so small. It should be increased. I am confused about font-padding, android width, layout margin left & right. What they means. How are they helping in the code. I have attached screenshot of this layout at this url:

http://imgur.com/a/oWipg

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >  

    <TableLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



    <TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" /> 


        <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_name"
                android:width="1dp"
              android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                 />
        <!-- android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" -->
        <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_name_value"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:width="1dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_email"
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                 />


        <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_email"

                    android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:width="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" 
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"    />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_username"
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                 />

        <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_username_value"

                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:width="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" 
                android:inputType="text"        />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_password"
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                 />

           <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_password_value"

                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:width="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" 
                android:inputType="textPassword"        />

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_retype_password"
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                 />

        <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_retype_password_value"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" 

                android:width="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"  
                android:inputType="textPassword"        />

       </TableRow>

        <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_address"
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                />

        <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_address_value"

                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" 
                android:width="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"  
                android:inputType="text"        />

        </TableRow>

       <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
           <TextView 
                android:text="@string/signup_phonenumber"
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                 />

           <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/signup_phonenumber_value"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"       
                android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" 
                android:width="1dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"    
                android:inputType="phone"       />

         </TableRow>
        <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_width="match_parent"  
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
           android:layout_gravity="center">
           <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/signup_agree"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/signup_agree"
                />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_width="match_parent"  
          android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button 
                android:id="@+id/signup_create_account"
                android:text="@string/signup_create_account"
                android:onClick="onClick5"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/signup_or"
                android:text="@string/signup_or" /> 
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    <Button
                android:id="@+id/signup_facebook"
                android:text="@string/signup_facebook"
                android:onClick="onClick6" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what you want please clarify?

Comment: just remove the width size like "android:width="1dp" instead of this write "android:width="Wrapcontent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_name" />
            <!-- android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" -->

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_name_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_username" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_username_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_password_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_retype_password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_retype_password_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_address"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_address_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:text="@string/signup_phonenumber" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_phonenumber_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/signup_agree"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/signup_agree" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signup_create_account"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick5"
                android:text="@string/signup_create_account" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/signup_or"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/signup_or" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signup_facebook"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onClick6"
                android:text="@string/signup_facebook" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is layout_weight? Is the one which help when screen size changes?

Comment: @user2929318 yes it'll adjuse for any screen.

Answer (score 0):

`marginright`- Distance of the element from the element at right

`marginleft` - Distance of the element from the element at left

`width`- width of the element

So if size is to be increased, increase the width of the element as well as the container element. You could give weight to elements for evenly distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Read and Understand this stuff it may help you very well bro ..

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_Android_Views,_View_Groups_and_Layouts